# How to select visible elements on screen?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How to select with CSS emements which actualy visible to user?

Actualy on screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a jQuery plugin that adds selectors to help you with this task of see if something is visible to the user or not (ViewPort).

You can see and [download it from here](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_viewport).

It basically adds the following selectors:

```
 $(":in-viewport")
 $(":below-the-fold")
 $(":above-the-top")
 $(":left-of-screen")
 $(":right-of-screen")
```

**And in your case I think the first one is the one you need.**
The others are more detailed, to determine the location of the visually hidden object.

Comment: The linked page doesn't exists anymore, the mentioned plugin can be found here: https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_viewport

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, use the :visible selector. `$("body").find(":visible")`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is with jQuery:

$('.testClass:visible')

Returns an array of all of the elements with class "testClass", that are visible in the DOM.

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: This is true, but the question is a bit different, OP asks for elements within visible viewport..

Answer (score 0):

there is no connection from screen to css (only from css to screen). The css is not able to select actual visible elements.

you can use jQuery to match those (as McNaney mentioned) and add them some existing css class.